# Getting error while generating barcode in php using barcodephp library

Tags: php, barcode

I am using the following code to generate barcode in php using [barcodephp](http://www.barcodephp.com/en/manual/ean13) this script

```
<?php
require('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require('class/BCGColor.php');
require('class/BCGDrawing.php');
require('class/BCGean13.barcode.php');

$font = new BCGFontFile('fontArial.ttf', 18);
$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

// Barcode Part
$code = new BCGean13();
$code->setScale(2);
$code->setThickness(30);
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
$code->setFont($font);
$code->parse('578124871412');

// Drawing Part
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
?>
```

I am getting following error, i have checked locations of library and everything is fine

[image]

What is the problem ??

Comment: the Problem is, that you or the code try to declare class BCGColor twice .. second declare is in BCGColor.php Line 11 ...

Comment: @donald123 where i am redeclaring BCGDrawing in this file ??

Comment: @donald123 i am only including it

Comment: It would appear that `BCGFontFile` already includes `BCGColor` and your inclusion is resulting in a duplicate definition. Try `require_once`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found the solution, just remove

```
require('class/BCGFontFile.php');
```